# Does changing a hash inside a hash not update the first one?

Tags: ruby, hash

In this example:

```
2.2.2 :001 > a = Hash.new(Hash.new)
 => {} 
2.2.2 :002 > a[1][2] = 3
 => 3 
2.2.2 :003 > a
 => {} 
2.2.2 :004 > a[1][2]
 => 3
```

after command `003`, I was expecting `{1=>{2=>3}}`. Why is this not the case, and how can I make it happen?

I tried to rehash, but that didn't solve my problem.

Comment: The string returned by `Hash#inspect` (line 3) doesn't contain the default hash. Use `a.default`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A hash's default value is what it returns when you try to access a key that isn't there. Accessing such a key won't actually add it to the hash, for that you'd need to use a `default_proc`:

```
d = { }
a = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = d }
```

Note that the default, `d`, is declared separately so that it will be shared. If you wanted to distinct default hash then you'd say:

```
Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = { } }
```

The [fine manual](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-c-new) might be useful here:

> **new → new_hash**
>   **new(obj) → new_hash**
>   **new {|hash, key| block } → new_hash**
>
> Returns a new, empty hash. If this hash is subsequently accessed by a key that doesn’t correspond to a hash entry, the value returned depends on the style of `new` used to create the hash. In the first form, the access returns `nil`. If *obj* is specified, this single object will be used for all *default values*. If a block is specified, it will be called with the hash object and the key, and should return the default value. It is the block’s responsibility to store the value in the hash if required.

The last sentence is important: if you want the key to be added to the hash, you'll have to make sure that happens yourself.